# Filter down list of elements by comparing their name properties to a list of potential partial matches

Tags: python, revit-api, pyrevit

I'm working in python and Revit, and I have a list of detail items with a name parameter. I'd like to filter my list down just the detail items where the name contains a partial match for any string in a list of partial matches. I have a working solution, but my intuition is telling me there ought to be a way to simplify it, since it doesn't feel very readable to me.

This works:

```
filtered_detail_items = filter(lambda x: filter_partial_match(
        key = x.LookupParameter('DMER_Panel_Name').AsString(),
        partial_keywords = ['TAP BOX', 'VFD', 'CONTROL PANEL', 'DISC'],
        inclusive = False),
    detail_items)
```

```
def filter_partial_match(key, partial_keywords, inclusive = True):

    # Allow user to pass in a single string or a list of strings.
    # If a single string, treat it as a list.
    if type(partial_keywords) is not list: partial_keywords = [ partial_keywords ]

    match_found = False
    if any(x in key for x in partial_keywords):
        match_found = True

    if inclusive:
        return match_found
    else:
        return not match_found
```

This doesn't:

```
filtered_detail_items = [(lambda x: (if any(y in x.LookParameter('DMER_Panel_Name').AsString() for y in ['TAP BOX', 'VFD', 'CONTROL PANEL', 'DISC']): x)) for x in detail_items ]
```

Comment: The body of a `lambda` has to be an expression. `if` is a statement, not an expression, you can't use it in `lambda`. You could use a conditional expression instead.

Comment: `LookupParameter` is pretty inefficient. I would suggest using it once only, before looping or searching, to retrieve the corresponding parameter `Definition` object. Then, in the loop, you can use the [`Parameter` property taking a `Definition` argument](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/87d8a88c-906e-85a9-f575-f263788b8584.htm) for more efficient access.

Comment: @JeremyTammik, Thanks I didn't know that was an option. I tried using `name_definition = riser_detail_items[0].LookupParameter('DMER_Panel_Name').Definition` but it didn't like me using [0] without first converting the set to a list with `ToElements()`. Also, is this how you'd access it? `x.Parameter(name_definition).AsString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments from [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791637/filter-down-list-of-elements-by-comparing-their-name-properties-to-a-list-of-pot#comment132000593_74791637) and [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74791730/5326807), here is the final solution I used:

```
#filter out partial_matches that we don't want in the names.
partial_matches = ['TAP BOX', 'VFD', 'CONTROL PANEL', 'DISC']

first_item = riser_detail_items.FirstElement()
if first_item:
    name_definition = first_item.LookupParameter('DMER_Panel_Name').Definition

riser_detail_items = [
    x for x in riser_detail_items
    if not any(
        partial_match in x.get_Parameter(name_definition).AsString()
        for partial_match in partial_matches
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `lambda` in a list comprehension. Call the function directly in the `if` condition of the generator.

```
filtered_detail_items = [
    x for x in detail_items 
    if filter_partial_match(
        key = x.LookupParameter('DMER_Panel_Name').AsString(),
        partial_keywords = ['TAP BOX', 'VFD', 'CONTROL PANEL', 'DISC'],
        inclusive = False)
]
```

If you want to do this without defining the `filter_partial_match()` function, you'd have to extract the code from the body and hard-code the parameters.

```
filtered_detail_items = [
    x for x in detail_items
    if not any(y in x.LookupParameter('DMER_Panel_Name').AsString() for y in ['TAP BOX', 'VFD', 'CONTROL PANEL', 'DISC'])
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I see now I was adding a lambda even though I've already defined a separate function. Not that this would necessarily improve readability, but is there any way to achieve the same result using a lambda instead of the filter_partial_match function? Or does the list of partial_keywords make this impossible?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it

Comment: I think the key variable would actually need to be defined inside the list comprehension since it depends on x, but the rest of the syntax looks good. I pulled out the list of partial matches as a separate variable for legibility. Thanks again!

Comment: Right, I got confused about what it depended on.

Comment: I was trying to avoid calling it every time through the generator in `any()`, but I don't think there's a way to avoid that in a list comprehension.